# Solving system of differential equations using elimination

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, systems-of-equations

I am trying to solve this system of differential equations using elimination method, but I am stuck.
$$\left.\left\{\begin{aligned}&y_1^{\prime}=y_2,\\&y_2^{\prime}=-y_1+\frac1{\cos x}.\end{aligned}\right.\right.$$
My attempt:

I tried differentiating the $y_1'= y_2$ again to get $y_1''= y_2'= -y_1+ \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$. But I am not sure how to proceed further. I've been suggested to use Lagrange method later, but I am not sure. I would appreciate if someone could help me get to the final solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You reduced the system to the second order ODE
$$
y_1''+y_1=\frac{1}{\cos x}. \tag{1}
$$
Next steps:

1. Find two linearly independent solutions to the homogeneous equation $y_1''+y_1=0$ --- for instance, $u(x)=\cos x$ and $v(x)=\sin x$;
2. Compute the Wronskian of those solutions:
   $$
   W[u,v]=uv'-u'v; \tag{2}
   $$
3. Find a particular solution to the equation $(1)$ using the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#General_second-order_equation)
   $$
   y_{1p}(x)=A(x)u(x)+B(x)v(x), \tag{3}
   $$
   where
   \begin{align}
   A(x)&=-\int\frac{v(x)}{W(x)\cos x}\,dx,\tag{4a} \\
   B(x)&=\int\frac{u(x)}{W(x)\cos x}\,dx; \tag{4b}
   \end{align}
4. The general solution to $(1)$ is given by
   $$
   y_1(x)=c_1u(x)+c_2v(x)+y_{1p}(x); \tag{5}
   $$
5. To find $y_2(x)$, use the first equation of the system:
   $$
   y_2(x)=y_1'(x)=c_1u'(x)+c_2v'(x)+y_{1p}'(x). \tag{6}
   $$

Comment: Note that this is very simple in this case, as $W=-1$.

Comment: @Gonçalo Thank you for answering. Could you please answer some additional questions I am having regarding the solution. The Wronskian I computed is $\cos^2x+\sin^2x$ (based on $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ you provided), is this correct? Furthermore, I am confused what is the point of 3. if we already have the general solution formula in 4. How does it derive from 3., or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: (1) You result for the Wronskian is correct; (2) If you include in Eq. $(3)$ the constants of integration of $A(x)$ and $B(x)$, then yes, Eq. $(3)$ gives the general solution to Eq. $(1)$. Eq. $(4)$ just emphasizes that the general solution to an inhomogeneous linear differential equation is the sum of a particular equation and the general solution to the homogeneous equation.

Comment: Correction: Instead of Eq. $(4)$ in my previous comment, I meant Eq. $(5)$.

Comment: @Gonçalo Thank you for your explanations. I just computed $A(x)=\text{log}(\text{cos}(x))+C_1$ and $B(x)=-x+C_2$. Am I correct in interpreting that $y_{p1}=(\text{ln}(\cos x)+C_1)(\cos x)+(-x+C_2)(\sin x)$ is the final solution to the problem? Is this the general solution? I am not really sure if I did well with the constants, though.

Comment: The correct expressions are $A(x)=\log|\cos x| + C_1$ and $B(x)=x+C_2$.

Comment: I finally finished computing $y_1=C_1\cos x +C_2\sin x + ((\cos  x)C_1+\cos x\text{log}(|\cos x|)+C_2\sin x+x\sin x)$ and $y_2=-C_1\sin x +C_2\cos x + ((C_2+x)(\cos x)-\sin x (C_1+\text{log}(|\cos x|)$. Is it correct, or have I made any more mistakes? Much thank you for the help. Are these now the general solutions?

Comment: The solution is correct, but it can be simplified a bit. For instance, you could write $y_1=c_1\cos x+c_2\sin x+\cos x\,\log|\cos x|+x\sin x$, where $c_1=2C_1$ and $c_2=2C_2$, and similarly for $y_2$.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think you can proceed further?

In this special case, due to the differential equation of the cosine, you can indeed integrate one step ahead:
$$
1=uy''-u''y=(uy'-u'y)'
\\
\implies x+c = uy'-u'y=\cos(x)y'(x)+\sin(x)y(x)
$$
In principle this is a linear DE of first order, you should know the solution algorithm or formula. The resulting terms will not be nice.

Comment: I've tried using formulas, but the answer I get $\begin{cases}y_2 = C_1\sin(t) + C\cos(t) \\
y_1 = C\sin(t) - C_1\cos(t) + \frac{1}{\cos(x)}
\end{cases} $ is wrong, so I am not sure what formula I should use?

Comment: You are trying for variation of constants? Then the left sides are zero and the right sides should be for the derivatives of the coefficients. Solve the system and integrate. After cancellations and trig. identities the solutions should be the same.